# answer never = guess no matter the input

Tags: python

My code will always take the first input despite the input. I have tried taking guess and making guess into an int but that leads to both if statements to trigger

```
x = 1
answer = 4
A=0
guess = 0
while A < 10:
    for _ in range (5):
    x = random.randint(1,5)
    print ("Ralph holds up " + str(x) +  " fingers what is the answer")
    guess=input()
    if guess != answer:
        print("WRONG PROGRESS RESET")
        A=0
        answer = x
    if guess == answer:
        A += 1
        print ("correct")
        print ("You have " + str(A) + " out of 10 finished")
        answer = x
print ("You win congrats")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It is important in python and for readability

Comment: What is `answer` the first time through the loop? After setting `answer = x`, though, `guess != answer` will *always* be true, because `guess` is a `str` and `answer` is an `int`.

Comment: Several things to check: 1. What is `answer` the first time through the loop? 2. `x` is an integer, but `guess` is a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Comment: Ah, now I get is, this is like the guessing-game in Monkey Island II. Note, however, that (besides casting the input to `int`) you should use `elif` for the second `if`, otherwise the user could guess both wrong and right in the same turn (by just guessing `x`).

Answer (score 0):

First off your code never even `import random` to use `randint`. But I'll assume you *did* import it and you just never pasted it in.

`input` reads your input as a `str`, but you want it to read as an `int`. All you really need to do is wrap the `input()` call in an `int` invocation. Additionally, `input` takes an argument, which prompts that argument in the console.

Also [@tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k) has a good point, but instead of `elif guess == answer:`, just use `else:`.

I also changed some variable logic, and I changed `A` to a much more meaningful identifier, as well as fixing formatting, like `a = b` is more aesthetically pleasing than `a=b`.

Oh and indentation. Indentation is important, not only for readability, but in *Python*, it's required. Python is whitespace significant, meaning scope delimiters are whitespace.

```py
import random
finished_count = 0

while finished_count < 10:
    for _ in range(5):
        answer = random.randint(1, 5)
        guess = int(input("Ralph holds up %d finger%s. What is the answer?\n" % (answer, "" if answer == 1 else "s")))
        if guess != answer: # incorrect answer
            print("WRONG PROGRESS RESET")
            finished_count = 0
        else: # correct
            finished_count += 1
            print("Correct. You have %d out of 10 finished" % finished_count)
print("You win, congrats!")
```

I just used this code up until I got to 10 and it works fine